Error TypeError al realizar consulta de SQL desde python
estoy intentado realizar una consulta al servidor de SQL desde un script de python, el problema es que al bajar los datos y convertirlos en una variable, me sale: <TypeError: sub() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'> No se que estoy haciendo mal, si alguien puede ayudarme, dejo aquí el codigo:
conn=pyodbc.connect(dbpath)
cursor1=conn.cursor()
consulta="SELECT Ingrediente, Peso FROM formula_micro WHERE Codigo = ?"
cursor1.execute(consulta, codigo)
datos=cursor1.fetchall()
print(datos)

La terimnal ubica el error en datos=cursor1.fetchall()

Hola Carlos, yo no puedo reproducirlo, pero mira a ver si esta issue en GitHub y la solución propuesta (pyodbc.setDecimalSeparator("."))  se ajusta a tu caso, es de hace un año y en entorno concreto, pero se ajusta al problema que planteas.

@FJSevilla Si, funcionó. Muchas gracias hermano. Voy a responder mostrando los cambios en el código y así, la respuesta queda. Muchas gracias de nuevo, esto lo tengo que mostrar mañana y estaba frenado en este problema.

Gracias al compañero @FJSevilla obtuve la respuesta. Es la publicada en el enlace de su comentario. Le dejo el código para cualquiera que tenga el mismo problema.
conn=pyodbc.connect(dbpath)
pyodbc.setDecimalSeparator(".")
cursor1=conn.cursor()
consulta="SELECT Ingrediente, Peso FROM formula_micro WHERE Codigo = ?"
cursor1.execute(consulta, [codigo])
datos=cursor1.fetchall()
print(datos)


¿Y cual fue el arreglo que hicistes?

Agregué : pyodbc.setDecimalSeparator(".")
en la segunda línea del código.
